# I want to fetch data from txt file to json format

Tags: json

I have a json file which is having some template already defined say:

```
{
  "ownerContext": 0,
  "databaseObjects": [
    {
      "objectName": "**CT_OPERATOR_ROUTE**",
      "dateColumnToFilter": "PRODUCTION_DAY",
      "whereCondition": "CREATED_BY IS NULL",
      "primaryKeyColumnList": null,
      "ignoreColumnList": [
        "DAYTIME"
      ],
      "includeAuditColumnList": [
        "CREATED_DATE",
        "CREATED_BY"
      ],
      "generateAnalysis": true,
      "analysisStrategy": "FULL_DETAILS"
    },
    {
      "objectName": "**DT_CT_EQPM_EQPOTHER**",
      "dateColumnToFilter": null,
      "whereCondition": null,
      "primaryKeyColumnList": null,
      "ignoreColumnList": [
        "DAYTIME"
      ]
...
}
```

suppose I have 1000 objects to get into the template then I have to to copy paste every single time,is there any way i can fetch object name from my .txt file and place it as value for object name

Comment: What language are you using? Js /python/java?

Comment: I am using Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is:

1. Read txt file, save `object name` in a list, maybe `List<String>`
2. Create POJO to map json object
3. Update `object name` to POJO using for-loop

Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> objectNames = getObjectNames();
        Context context = updateObjectName(objectNames);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(context);
        System.out.println(json);
    }

    private static List<String> getObjectNames() throws IOException {
        Path path = Path.of("api/src/main/resources/test.txt");
        return Files.readAllLines(path);
    }

    public static Context updateObjectName(List<String> objectNames) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setOwnerContext(0);
        List<DatabaseObject> databaseObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String name : objectNames) {
            DatabaseObject dbObject = new DatabaseObject();
            dbObject.setObjectName(name);
            databaseObjects.add(dbObject);
        }
        context.setDatabaseObjects(databaseObjects);
        return context;
    }

    @Data
    static class Context {
        private int ownerContext;
        private List<DatabaseObject> databaseObjects;
    }

    @Data
    static class DatabaseObject {
        private String objectName;
        private String dateColumnToFilter;
    }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "ownerContext" : 0,
  "databaseObjects" : [ {
    "objectName" : "Object A",
    "dateColumnToFilter" : null
  }, {
    "objectName" : "Object B",
    "dateColumnToFilter" : null
  }, {
    "objectName" : "Object C",
    "dateColumnToFilter" : null
  } ]
}
```

For library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: When I am trying to build the code it is giving me an error as
java: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
I have added all the dependencies

Comment: Hi friend, you have to deal by yourself. I've already written it all for you.